# Temperature logger compatible with Mac?

Tags: hardware, usb, data-transfer, temperature, compatibility

I'd like to measure the temperature in my fridge over a few days and graph the results, since I think the fridge may be starting to fail.

So I'm looking for a cheap device which can run independently on battery power, which logs the temperature and timestamp every few seconds to a file.  I want to plug this in to my Mac and retrieve the data.  I don't particularly need software to generate the graph: I can do this with Numbers, Excel etc.

This ["RC-4" unit](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Temperature-Recorder-Warehousin-Refrigerated-Laboratory/dp/B00ININON6) pictured below is the sort of thing I'm imagining.  However, it doesn't seem to be Mac compatible.

[image: "RC-4" temperature logger]

Can anyone recommend a suitable product?

Alternatively, I could set up a Windows installation for this device in VirtualBox, but I wonder if that would handle the USB drivers correctly.  Can anyone offer any experience here?

Answer (score 2):

The [Go!Temp](http://www.vernier.com/products/sensors/temperature-sensors/go-temp/) from Vernier works a charm for me! 50 USD with free [software download](http://www.vernier.com/downloads/).

Comment: wow, that is expensive to confirm that the old fridge is old :)!

Comment: Thanks - I hadn’t found that product. It looks well designed, and it is good to have native Mac software. But 1) it doesn’t run independently: it needs to be connected to a computer to operate, and I don’t have one near the fridge, and 2) it is more than twice the price of the RC-4. More suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable writing a few lines of Python, [elitech-datareader](https://github.com/civic/elitech-datareader/) seems to be an option to pull data from the RC-4 onto a Mac. I just ordered an RC-5 on eBay, and will update this answer once I'm able to test it out.